# Can a bash function be used in different scripts?

Tags: bash, function

I've got a function that I want to reference and use across different scripts. Is there any way to do this? I don't want to be re-writing the same function for different scripts. Thanks.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Sure - in your script, where you want to use the function, you can write a command like

```
source function.sh
```

which is equivalent to including the contents of `function.sh` in the file at the point where the command is run. Note that `function.sh` needs to be in one of the directories in `$PATH`; if it's not, you need to specify an absolute path.

Comment: function.sh can be anywhere in your PATH. If bash is in posix mode, it will not look in the current directory. This is all explained in the man page.

Comment: True, I had it mixed up with other things.

Comment: Let's say `function.sh` has some code in it too.  Will `source function.sh` also execute the code?

Comment: @user1527227 yes, the command `source function.sh` is equivalent to including the contents of the file `function.sh` at that same point in the script.

Comment: This is misleading. This doesn't load a specific function but rather a whole file. Also, naming a script "function" is a **terrible** idea.

Comment: @Pithikos of course, I explicitly said that writing `source function.sh` is equivalent to including the contents of the file in the script. I never claimed that it would load a specific function. Also, `function.sh` is meant as a generic name, like `example.com`; I never actually suggested using it as the name for a real file.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can localize all your functions in a common file (or files). This is exactly what I do with all my utility functions. I have a single `utility.shinc` in my home directory that's used by all my programs with:

```
. $HOME/utility.shinc
```

which executes the script in the context of the current shell. This is important - if you simply run the include script, it will run in a subshell and any changes will not propagate to the current shell.

You can do the same thing for groups of scripts. If it's part of a "product", I'd tend to put all the scripts, and any included scripts, in a single shell directory to ensure everything is localized.

Answer (score -4):

Yes..you can!
Add **source function_name** in your script.
I prefer to create variable eg.VAR=$(funtion_name),if you add the source function_name after #!/bin/bash then your script first execute imported function task and then your current script task so its better to create variable and used anywhere in script.
thank you..Hope its work for you:)

Comment: Why are you copying answers that have been posted... 8 years ago?

Comment: For better understanding..I have posted more briefly then previous one.