# How to define a bash function for use in any script?

Tags: bash, function, export

I'd like to define it once and use it anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I basically agree with @eduffy, I typically put such functions in a file either in the user's home directory or if the scripts are shared between users in a directory in the user's path. I would then source the file `(. ~/FILE or . $(type -p FILE))` in the .bash_profile. This allows you to 're-source' the file if necessary (i.e., you change something in it) w/o having to re-login, etc.

Comment: But any readers need to also realize you have to export the function name like this: export -f funcname.

Comment: export is usually optional for sourced files since they are executed in the environment in which they are executed. Everything defined in FILE will be available in the user's shell for subsequent scripts (unless unset). Exporting is needed when you want to make a variable (or function) visible to sub-shells during execution of the parent shell.

Answer (score 8):

In bash, you can run `source` from your script (with the file containing your functions as the argument) and simply call the function.  This is what happens implicitly when you define the function in your `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Yes, short answer: Import the script with the `source`, or single dot `.`, command

Answer (score 6):

Place your "common" function in a separate script (let's call it "a"):

```
#!/bin/bash

test_fun () {
    echo "hi"
}
```

Next, "import" it into another script (say, "b"):

```
#!/bin/bash

. ./a

test_fun
```

Running `bash b` will output "hi"

Comment: This didn't work for me. However, doing `source ../a` worked, as described in this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1016415/16524

Comment: Why is the initial hashbang line required in file "a"? Since "a" is not intended to be run as an executable, only sourced from an existing Bash environment, the hashbang is never used, and possibly is actually misleading? (since it suggests the file is usefully executable, which it is not)

Answer (score 2):

Put it in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: .bash_profile is only sourced by login shell, so .bashrc is the correct place for functions and aliases. It's different from environment variables, which are passed to the child process from parent.

Comment: I've tried it in both files and opened new terminal windows and it doesn't work in either.  I've tried exporting it from .bashrc and that doesn't help either.

Comment: However, "compgen -A function" can find it.

Comment: @cababunga: No! Put it in ~/.bash_profile and follow it with export  -f funcname.

Comment: @grok12 If you shell out from a parent process, such as if you execute `:sh` from within `vim`, anything that appears in `.bash_profile` only, and not in `.bashrc`, will not be visible within that environment.